# changing a property value in an array

Tags: swift

when i try to assign a new value to an array property i get the error :
Cannot assign to property: 'color' is a 'let' constant

```
struct car {
    let model: String
    let color: String
}

var myCars :[car] = [
    car(name:"model X", color: "black"),
    car(name:"model Y", color: "blue"),
    car(name:"roadster", color: "red"),
    car(name:"model S", color: "black"),
    car(name:"model 3", color: "black")
]

let colorFilter = dataSource.items.index(where: {$0.color == "black"})
myCars[colorFilter].color = "grey"
```

replace all the items with color property set to "black" with "grey"

Comment: Then declare the property as `var`, `var color: String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `color` is a `constant (let) property`, i.e. once `initialised` you cannot change its value. In case you want to modify the value of `color`, make it `var` instead of `let`

```
struct car {
    let model: String
    var color: String
}
```

To update the `color` of all `cars` from `black to grey`, use **`map(_:)`** on `myCars` array.

```
myCars = myCars.map {
    var newCar = $0
    if newCar.color == "black" {
        newCar.color = "grey"
    }
    return newCar
}
```

**Output:**

```
print(myCars)

// [car(model: "model X", color: "grey"), car(model: "model Y", color: "blue"), car(model: "roadster", color: "red"), car(model: "model S", color: "grey"), car(model: "model 3", color: "grey")]
```

Comment: how do i delete all the items with color property set to "black"

Answer (score 0):

In your car struct, you defined color with let so it is a constant. Change it to var if you want it to be variable.

```
struct car {
    let model: String
    var color: String
}
```